# Java: What's the difference between format specifiers %x and %h?

Tags: java, format

Looking at the [specification page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax), I see that `%h` calls into [Integer.toHexString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString%28int%29), but I can't find any practical difference between the two specifiers.

Can you give an example where using the to specifiers on the same input yields different results?

```
System.out.println(String.format("%1$h %1$x", 123));
```

This prints

```
7b 7b
```

Comment: Try passing a `null` to the formatter.

Comment: No, it calls `Integer.toHexString(arg.hashCode())` which is a *very* different thing.

Comment: The descriptions are pretty different; `%h` calls toHexString on the hashCode of the arg.

Comment: Well, one only accepts integral types, the other accepts any (reasonable) type.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `%h` specifier invokes `hashCode` on its argument (provided it is not `null`, when you get "null"), whereas the `%x` specifier just formats its argument as a hexadecimal integer. This makes a major difference if the thing being formatted isn't an integer. See the examples here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html

In particular, the fact that you get the same results for integers is a result of the fact that `Integer.hashCode` returns the integer itself:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#hashCode%28%29

Answer (score 7):

The [page you provided](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) states:

> 'h' If the argument arg is null, then the result is "null". Otherwise, the result is obtained by invoking Integer.toHexString(arg.hashCode()).

and

> 'x' The result is formatted as a hexadecimal integer

So `%h` prints `null` if the provided object was `null`, otherwise `%h` prints the hash code of the object. Whereas `%x` prints the hex-value of the provided  `int` value.

**Edit**: as pointed out in the comments: if no value for `%x` is given an `IllegalFormatConversionException` is thrown, as stated here:

> If a format specifier contains a conversion character that is not applicable to the corresponding argument, then an IllegalFormatConversionException will be thrown.

So basically, you'd just needed to read the page you provided... :)

Comment: What does `%x` do when not passed an integer?

Comment: It would throw `IllegalFormatConversionException`.

Answer (score 5):

`%h` prints the hashcode of an object in hexidecimal.

`%x` prints a number in hexidecimal.

For `Integer` the hashCode and the value are the same. For `Long` the value and the hashCode can be different.

```
System.out.printf("%h%n", "hello world");
System.out.printf("%h%n", 0x1234567890L);
System.out.printf("%x%n", 0x1234567890L);
```

prints

```
6aefe2c4
34567882
1234567890
```